# Transfer case vs Wheel alignment

Tags: maintenance

I have a 1999 mercury mountaineer AWD
Had four new tires put on at Wal-Mart about 2 weeks ago as I was backing up. It mad a clunk notice and short grinding notice. Never did before. I had had work done on it when first bought about 3 yrs ago which had something at that time to do with AWD. Now clicking notice only when turn corner in front. Took to garage says not 100% positive but thinks could be transfer case. When I told him just had tires put on all way round. He asked if I had an alignment I said no. Would or could an alignment fix this

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm pretty sure an alignment isn't going to do anything for you here. I will say, though, getting the alignment at least checked with new tires is a must. They cost too much to tear them up within a couple thousand miles due to bad alignment. Well worth the extra money.

Comment: An alignment in itself would not cause the issue.The mechanic may have been doing some pre-diagnostic thinking. If you had an alignment done, it could rule out worn steering parts as you can't do a proper alignment with worn parts. He may also have been thinking if an alignment had been done could something have come loose afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common sources of a clicking sound while turning is a wearing or worn CV (constant velocity) joint. This is the flexible joint that allows the axle to rotate while the wheel is turned or moves up and down with the suspension. While the joint is available as a separate piece it is typically replaced as a rebuilt axle assembly. This consists of the inner and outer CV joints and the axle shafts.